# Disable/Turn Off URL Rewrite Module in Windows Azure Web Role

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, azure, azure-web-roles

We are using Windows Azure Web Roles to host our MVC 3 application.  From many of the performance related questions here on SO, I have seen that the URL Rewrite module can have a performance impact on an MVC 3 application, even when not being used.

With that said, is there a way in either the web.config or ServiceDefinition files to disable or remove the URL Rewrite module on Azure?  One way that I have thought about is using a .cmd file on startup, similar to what we use to extend the App Pool timeout and recycle periods on the application, but cannot find a command line method of disabling the module.

[URL Rewrite on by default on Azure Web Roles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd573358.aspx)

[Impact of URL Rewrite on Server](http://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2011/09/aspnet-mvc-performance-tips.html)

[Method of increasing App Pool timeout on Azure](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/controlling-application-pool-idle-timeouts-in-windows-azure)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which version of the SDK are you using? Version 1.3 and higher don't install it by default. See the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg465715.aspx#IIS):

> If you wish to use the IIS URL Rewrite module, **you must install it** and
>   configure your rewrite rules. See URL Rewrite Module for more
>   information.

**Update:**

I've double checked and it seems that URL Rewrite 2 is still installed on the Web Roles (I'm using the 1.7 SDK). To uninstall URL Rewrite, create a startup task (elevated) that executes the following:

```
wmic product where name="IIS URL Rewrite Module 2" call uninstall
```

Comment: I believe it is SDK 1.7 (latest) and we have no options of selecting the IIS role on/off, etc.  Basically, in VS, we say, new Web Role -> include our MVC project and off we go.

Comment: just got around to getting this into our startup script.  RDP into the Azure cluster and appears to have worked well.